# Migrating a question to a different SE site or asking for more attention

Tags: support, specific-question, migration

I'm posting in meta for the first time so please don't mind some culturally outrageous thing that I would end up doing here and inform me about my peculiarities. So I have this question on stack exchange physics, [about the fermi level of materials](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/351374/) and I have not received any assistance on it as of yet. Couls you let me know if there's some way to give my question more attention or if I could move the same question to a different forum like Chemistry and then see the responses because I really need to have this discussion and I know that there are people on this site who could really be able to help me with this work.

Comment: You could delete your question from this site and ask it on Chemistry SE. Duplicates are not encouraged.

Comment: You have two major problems with your question on the main site. The biggest problem is that you have written a large block of text. Users like me see that and go "Uh oh. I'll have to read through a lot of complex stuff and decipher the question out of it. Sounds like a lot of time to put into it just to see if I even can answer it. Nah, I'll go answer an easier question". Break it into manageable paragraphs, bold the question, be clear and explicit, don't give more info than needed (unless you make it fun).

Comment: Your other problem is that this is a relatively niche topic. Fewer people will be able to answer your question. That leads even the best written questions to be left alone for a while. There is no solution to this problem

Answer (score 4):

There may be a bit of chemistry, but I read this as being a primarily physics question. It's technically possible for you to delete the question from here and re-post it on Chemistry.SE. Make sure not to cross-post it; that is frowned on.

However, I'd say leave it here. As for getting more attention, try improving clarity and presentation. The easier and quicker someone can read your post and get the details and question, the more likely they are to answer or, filing that, upvote (which increases likelihood of an answer). If you have doubts about that, try offering a bounty on your question. You spend some of your own reputation to have your question featured in the bounties page for a week. That's probably the best way of drawing more attention to it.

If you don't like any of those options, you could ask the people on [the h Bar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) if they can answer the question and then provide them with the link to it. Failing all that AND if there's some special circumstances (like the question gets unfairly closed, severely downvoted, or people express problems that you want advice on how to fix), you could also try advertising the question here on meta (much like you've already done. Kudos for following my advice).

Comment: Thanks a lot Jim, this was definitely helpful :)

Comment: It definitely is physics, not chemistry. I added a comment today pointing a few things out that kept me from answering - a good answer would be a book (and I suggested one).